# Reading from PubsubIO writing to DatastoreIO

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible to create a pipeline that reads data from Pub/Sub and writes to Datastore? In my code I specify the PubsubIO as the input, and apply windowing to get a bounded PCollection, but it seems that it is not possible to use the DatastoreIO.writeTo with the options.setStreaming as true, while that is required in order to use PubsubIO as input. Is there a way around this? Or is it simply not possible to read from pubsub and write to datastore?

Here's my code:

```
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create()
            .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

    options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);
    options.setProject(projectName);
    options.setStagingLocation("gs://my-staging-bucket/staging");
    options.setStreaming(true);

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<String> input = p.apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic("projects/"+projectName+"/topics/event-streaming"));
    PCollection<String> inputWindow = input.apply(Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(5))).triggering(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)).discardingFiredPanes().withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(1)));
    PCollection<String> inputDecode = inputWindow.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String msg = c.element();
            byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(msg.getBytes());
            String outmsg = new String(decoded);
            c.output(outmsg);
        }
    }));
    PCollection<DatastoreV1.Entity> inputEntity = inputDecode.apply(ParDo.of(new CreateEntityFn("stream", "events")));

    inputEntity.apply(DatastoreIO.writeTo(datasetid));


    p.run();
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Write transform is not supported by the Dataflow streaming runner.
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner$StreamingWrite.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:488)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner$StreamingWrite.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:480)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.apply(PipelineRunner.java:74)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:314)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:358)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:267)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:312)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:358)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:267)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:159)
at my.own.project.google.dataflow.EventStreamingDataflow.main(EventStreamingDataflow.java:104)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DatastoreIO sink is not currently supported in the streaming runner.  To write to Datastore from a streaming pipeline, you can make direct calls to the Datastore API from a DoFn.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. But now I am facing problems with calling the Datastore API from the Dataflow app, which is not an AppEngine app, and apparently the datastore API relies a lot on AppEngine functionality only available for apps running on AppEngine. Then I found the Remote API which seems to provide exactly what I need, but I'm still facing difficulties using it. Do I need to authenticate with a service account? I followed the code sample on this [page] (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) but I'm getting a HttpResponseException, 302

Comment: Are you trying to write to a Datastore instance that belongs to different project from your Dataflow pipeline?  If so, take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#cross-project for how to set that up

Comment: No, the datastore instance is part of the same project as the dataflow, I got over that 302 problem. BUT, how is it possible to use the Remote API in a ParDo, when (I'm guessing here) ParDo runs the DoFn function in different thread or instance than the parent pipeline, and the remote API installer is not serializable, and the installer is only available on the thread where it was created? I'm not sure if this is the problem, but anyway, I'm getting  different exceptions depending on where I try to create and access the installer..

Comment: Or am I on the wrong path here with the Remote API? Should I be able to call the datastore API from a dataflow pipeline if they are part of the same project?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after a lot of banging my head against the wall, I finally got it working. Like danielm suggested, I'm making calls to the Datastore API from a ParDo DoFn. One problem was, that I didn't realize there is a separate API for using the Cloud Datastore outside from AppEngine. (com.google.api.services.datastore... vs. com.google.appengine.api.datastore...). Another problem was that apparently there is some kind of bug in the latest version of the Cloud Datastore API (google-api-services-datastore-protobuf v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0, I got an IllegalAccessError), I resolved that by using an older version (v1beta2-rev1-2.1.2).

So, here's my working code:

```
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.PubsubIO;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1.*;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.client.Datastore;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreException;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreFactory;
import static com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreHelper.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

//--------------------

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create()
            .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

    options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);
    options.setProject(projectName);
    options.setStagingLocation("gs://my-staging-bucket/staging");
    options.setStreaming(true);

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    PCollection<String> input = p.apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic("projects/"+projectName+"/topics/my-topic-name"));

    input.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws ParseException, DatastoreException {

            JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(c.element());

            Datastore datastore = null;
            try {
                datastore = DatastoreFactory.get().create(getOptionsFromEnv()
                        .dataset(datasetid).build());
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException exception) {
                System.err.println("Security error connecting to the datastore: " + exception.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("I/O error connecting to the datastore: " + exception.getMessage());
            }

            Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey("my-kind");
            keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespace("my-namespace");
            Entity.Builder event = Entity.newBuilder()
                    .setKey(keyBuilder);

            event.addProperty(makeProperty("my-prop",makeValue((String)json.get("my-prop"))));

            CommitRequest commitRequest = CommitRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setMode(CommitRequest.Mode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL)
                    .setMutation(Mutation.newBuilder().addInsertAutoId(event))
                    .build();
            if(datastore!=null){
                datastore.commit(commitRequest);
            }

        }
    }));


    p.run();
}
```

And the dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
  <version>[1.0.0,2.0.0)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-datastore-protobuf</artifactId>
  <version>v1beta2-rev1-2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.17.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Some more.. like JUnit etc..  -->
```